# Adjective vs Past Participle(used as an adjective) derived from the same word

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I have a quick question: what's the difference between these two noun + adjective forms.

> - The ripe apple.
> - The ripened apple.

From my understanding, use of past participle as an adjective suggests the maker: as if someone has made the apple ripe.

I'll be very glad to know what native-english speakers think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of a past participle as an adjective can suggest a maker if the verb is one of making.

- *ripe* is a stative adjective.
  It can occur as a predicate adjective, with an auxiliary *be*. But not in the progressive.
  I.e, you can say *The apple is ripe*, but not **The apple is being ripe*.
- *ripen* is a causative/inchoative verb meaning  either

  - 'to become ripe' (the intransitive inchoative sense),
    or
  - 'to cause to become ripe' (the transitive causative sense).

The causative sense can be a verb of making, with an agent subject

- *These apples have been ripened with ethylene; they are ripened apples.*

But *ripened apples* can also simply mean *apples that have ripened* (perfect construction from the inchoative), 
as well as *apples that have been ripened* (perfect passive construction from causative).