# verbs ending in -en

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Which words in English have the **-en** form (such as in "***brighten*** the day", "***hasten*** the steps"  )? Rather than some explicit list, I am looking for the class of words in terms of its origin/etymology.

I guess it is a somewhat literary/archaic form to use, but I am still unsure whether my US English auto-correct is showing it wrong for certain verbs out of ignorance (by which I mean out of Americanisation of English) or simply because such forms do not exist for those particular verbs.

In particular, is ".. to cracken up a tin can." correct?

Comment: ***-en***: - 
*word-forming element making verbs (such as darken, weaken) from adjectives or nouns, from Old English -nian, from Proto-Germanic  -inojan (also source of Old Norse -na), from PIE adjectival suffix -no-. **Most active in Middle English.*** http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-en&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: Why would you put a verb ending on a verb? Unless you want to poetically imply a sea monster opens the tin can that does not seem advisable.

Comment: If you have an adjective or noun, you can often turn it into a verb by adding *-en*: *Lighten, darken, redden, fasten, strengthen, weaken, shorten*. And in fact, if you use it on an adjective that isn't traditionally verbened this way, it will often be understandable: for example, *nicen* and *embiggen*. But it's pointless to use it on words that are already verbs like *crack*.

Comment: You're may be confusing it with verbs that form that past participle by adding *-en* like *taken* or *shaken*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffix *-en* is an old **Inchoative/Causative** inflection. It isn't productive any more, however.

The point is not that *-en* makes a verb out of whatever it attaches to -- that's incidental and almost irrelevant. It's necessary because change of state and causation are expressed by verbs, and that's what Inchoative and [Causative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/74536/15299) mean.

*-en* can attach to adjectives ([*ripen*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/299637/15299) 'become *ripe*; cause to become *ripe*'), especially some colors (*redden* 'become *red*; cause to become *red*'; *whiten, darken, lighten*), but not others (**bluen*, **purplen*, **greyen*, **greenen*).

Interestingly, [this suffix can also occur as a prefix](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57678/15299) (*enjoy* 'become joyful', *enrich* 'become/cause to become rich', *enfeeble,* etc). They can even occur together, as in *enlighten*, which means something different from *lighten*.